# How to require users to request group membership?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have a User model, a group model (Cliq), and a group_membership model (Cliq_Membership). Everything seems to be working fine so far. I currently have it so that when a User creates a group they "own" it and when an "owner" leaves the group (destroys their group membership) the entire group is destroyed. A group has one owner and many members. I want to make it so that a User has to request to be a "member". I want the "owner" to be the only one to see the requests and accept/deny the requests.

For Clarity:

- I want users to have to request to be group members
- I want Cliqs to be able to request Users to be members
- Only the owner should be able to see/accept/deny friend requests
- I want the relationship to be "two-way/self-referential"; that is, I want the User/Member to be shown as being included in the group and the group as having another member
- Cliqs = Groups

How do you accomplish this?

Here is my code so far:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :uploads
 has_one :owned_cliq, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Cliq', dependent: :destroy

 has_many :cliq_memberships
 has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships
end

class CliqMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cliq
 belongs_to :user
end

class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

 has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user

end
```

Controllers:

```
class CliqMembershipsController < ApplicationController

def create
    #Cliq or Cliq_ID?
    @cliq = Cliq.find(params[:cliq])

    @cliq_membership = current_user.cliq_memberships.build(cliq: @cliq)
    @cliq.members << current_user

    if @cliq_membership.save
        flash[:notice] = "Joined #{@cliq.name}"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Not able to join Cliq."
    end
    redirect_to cliq_url
end

def destroy
    @cliq_membership = current_user.cliq_memberships.find(params[:id])
    @cliq = @cliq_membership.cliq

    if @cliq.owner == current_user
       @cliq.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Cliq has been deleted."
       redirect_to current_user
    else
    @cliq_membership.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "You left the Cliq."
    redirect_to current_user
    end
end
end

class CliqsController < ApplicationController

def show
    @cliq = Cliq.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @cliq = Cliq.new(params[:id])
end

def create
    @cliq = current_user.build_owned_cliq(cliq_params)
    @cliq.members << current_user

    if @cliq.save
        redirect_to current_user
    else
        redirect_to new_cliq_path
    end
end

def destroy
    #@cliq = current_user.owned_cliq.find(params[:id])
    #lash[:alert] = "Are you sure you want to delete your Cliq? Your Cliq and all of its associations will be permanently deleted."
    #@cliq.destroy

    #if @cliq.destroy
       #redirect_to current_user
       #flash[:notice] = "You deleted the Cliq."
    #else
        #redirect_to current_user
        #set up error handler
        #flash[:notice] = "Failed to delete Cliq."
    #end
end


def cliq_params
    params.require(:cliq).permit(:name, :cliq_id)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another model and controller for handling user requests

create `request.rb` model

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :cliq
end
```

create `requests_controller.rb`.

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_group  
  before_action :auth_group_owner 
  before_action :find_request, except: [:index, :create]

  def index
  end

  def create
    @grp.requests.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    # redirect the user
  end

  def approv
    # add the user to the group
    @request.destroy
    # redirect
  end

  def destroy
    #delete the request
  end

  private

  def set_group
    #find group @grp
  end

  def auth_group_owner
   if current_user != @grp.owner
    redirect
   end
  end

  def find_request
    #find request
  end

end
```

your `routes.rb`

```
resources :groups do
  resources :requests, only: [:index, :destroy] do
    member do
      get 'approv'
    end   
  end
end
```

Comment: How would I create(send) a request?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work without creating a new model for requests. Adding a new boolean field to CliqMembership model to store whether a particular cliq_memberhip is confirmed or not is sufficient. (Let's call that field 'confirmed', for example)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cliq_memberships
  has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships
  has_many :confirmed_memberships, -> { confirmed }, class_name: "CliqMembership"
  has_many :confirmed_cliqs, through: :confirmed_memberships, source: :cliq
end

class CliqMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cliq
  belongs_to :user

  scope :confirmed, -> { where(confirmed: true) }
end

class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user
  has_many :confirmed_memberships, { confirmed }, class_name: "CliqMembership"
  has_many :confirmed_members, through: :confirmed_memberships, source: :user
end
```

With this, you can set the value of `confirmed` field to `false` by default when a new cliq_membership is created by a user. Until the owner `update`'s that particular cliq_membership to change the value of `confirmed` to `true`.

Assuming `user` & `cliq` are instances of User model & Cliq model respectively, you can now use `user.confirmed_cliqs` and `cliq.confirmed_members`.

Edit:

In order to restrict the edit & update actions on cliq_membership to only the cliq owner, you can use a *before filter*.

```
class CliqMembershipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :cliq_owner, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
    @cliq_membership = CliqMembership.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @cliq_membership = CliqMembership.find(params[:id])
    @cliq_membership.update_attributes(cliq_membership_params)
  end

  private
    def cliq_membership_params
      params.require(:cliq_membership).permit(:cliq_id, :user_id, :confirmed)
    end

    def cliq_owner
      @cliq = CliqMembership.find(params[:id]).cliq
      redirect_to root_url unless @cliq.owner == current_user
    end
end
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This seems REALLY close to what I've been trying to get at. How should I alter my controller actions? And how do I send a request to users from the Cliq/Cliq-Owner?

Comment: You will need `edit` & `update` actions in `CliqMembershipsController` to update the `confirmed` field from false to true. I updated the answer to include how to restrict the privilege to the cliq owner.

Comment: That makes sense. How would the Cliq send a request to a User for the User to respond and join the Cliq?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the update/edit controller actions would look like?

Comment: To send requests to users to join a cliq, the owner could create new cliq_membership objects with `user_id`s of the users he wants as members. Then on users' dashboard/show page, you could show them the cliq_memberships requested by different cliq owners. To keep track of this, you will likely need more fields in the CliqMembership model just as you needed `confirmed` field to track the membership confirmation.

Comment: If you're looking for some sort of a notification system to alert users of the membership requests sent to them by different cliq owners, the implementation will be somewhat different.